# Designing tables from mySQL database

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I need help on designing my database.
What would be the most efficient way to make my database?
I have 18 categories on my list, each one of those categories has 4 items to choose from and from each of those items there's 3 sizes each.
I tried making it from a single table but it looks unorganized, any ideas how? thanks.

Comment: Did you try to split it up in multiple tables, how far did you get?

Comment: I'm just new in mysql. I tried making them on one table. it looks messy

Comment: A google search will give you plenty of learning resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First jot out the relation between these 3 entities.
I presume that you have Categories(1): Items(M) relation and Items(1):Sizes(M) as per your description.

So, the best way to design is to make three tables each of Categories,Items and Sizes and associate each one of them in 1:M i.e Categories<->Items (1:M) and Items<->Size (1:M)

This would make your database normalized without redundancy of data.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks alot! I forgot to put the price and stock btw. So in price and stock, i'll be creating a new table too?

Comment: Prices and stock would be another table but will have the key of each of the above 3 tables. Vote up the answer if you feel it was helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are describing a basic star schema with snowflakes .. That's the real name , your main table will have N dimensions each dimension will have his separate table.

Your facts will be counter for the objects at the main table for example.

http://infogoal.com/datawarehousing/images/orders_star_schema_01.png